# Pagination with custom SQL query

Tags: wp-query, pagination, navigation, wpdb, sql

I have my own SQL string to select Custom Post Type posts with specific WHERE clause. I've used the offset and limit to return appropriate posts depending on a page being displayed. That's working fine.

Now, I would like to make `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` functions work. They both are called from `get_posts_nav_link` which uses `global $wp_query`.

Is there a way I can re-assign `global $wp_query` with my SQL string or `$wpdb->get_results` results or anything else? So the native `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` WP functions would work.

If not, how can I reproduce the prev and next post link functions?

I would really appreciate any help and advice! I'm totally stuck with this.
Thanks :)

**NOTE:** I have just noticed that `previous_posts_link()` is working correctly on all the pages, but `no idea why` and in this case, why `next_posts_link` doesn't work :S

Here is the code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
$offset = ($paged - 1)*$post_per_page;

$sql = "
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.*, wp_postmeta.* 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1  
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'movie' 
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
    AND ((wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_expiry_date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) >= '".$current_date."') 
        OR (mt1.meta_key = '_expiry_date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = ''))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$post_per_page;

$movies_all_current = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, OBJECT);

if($movies_all_current) {
global $post;

//loop
foreach( $movies_all_current as $key=>$post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    //display each post
    //...
} //end foreach ?>

    //navigation
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="previous panel"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; newer') ?></div>
    <div class="next panel"><?php next_posts_link('older &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I got there at the end. I couldn't use `WP_Query` class as I really needed to have my own pretty big and complex SQL. Here is what I ended up having:

In `functions.php` I have my custom SQL and logic for counting the values needed for the WP pagination logic:

```
function vacancies_current( ){
    global $wpdb, $paged, $max_num_pages, $current_date;

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $post_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
    $offset = ($paged - 1)*$post_per_page;

    /* Custom sql here. I left out the important bits and deleted the body 
     as it will be specific when you have your own. */
    $sql = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  {$wpdb->posts}.*
        FROM {$wpdb->posts}
        ....
        GROUP BY {$wpdb->posts}.ID 
        ORDER BY {$wpdb->posts}.post_date DESC
        LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$post_per_page."; ";   

    $sql_result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, OBJECT);

    /* Determine the total of results found to calculate the max_num_pages
     for next_posts_link navigation */
    $sql_posts_total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT FOUND_ROWS();" );
    $max_num_pages = ceil($sql_posts_total / $post_per_page);

    return $sql_result;
}
```

Then in my template file I'd have:

```
<?php 
    $vacancies_current = vacancies_current();
    /*followed by a standart loop to display your results */ 
 ?>
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="previous panel"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; previous vacancies',$max_num_pages) ?></div>
    <div class="next panel"><?php next_posts_link('more vacancies &raquo;',$max_num_pages) ?></div>
</div>
```

The trick was in supplying `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link` the `$max_num_pages` value and obviously in calculating it correctly.

This works very well. Hope it will help someone :)

Dasha

Comment: +1 nice work.  I came across this (and borrowed heavily, thanks) while researching my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057059/wordpress-order-by-author-if-different-than-admin. I was wondering if you know of a way to use a custom SQL statement like this, but in a pre_get_posts() action as per https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Removing_query_posts_from_the_main_loop?  I find this solution is susceptible to the 404 on last page issue, as per http://wordpress.org/support/topic/explanation-and-workaround-for-error-404-on-category-pagination?replies=14. How did you overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Custom Queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) - which allow you to modify the wp_query call in many interesting and useful ways, and push the results back into your global query object.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Anu's answer.  Instead of relying on your custom sql query you could use the [WP_Query class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and let WordPress handle all the heavy SQL lifting.  This would surely solve your navigation issue.

Example query for movie post type within your _expiry_date meta_key:

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'movie',
    'meta_query' => array(
            'meta_key' => '_expiry_date',
            'meta_value' => $today,
            'meta_compare' => '< '
                    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'order'    => 'DESC'
    );

    $movie_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $movie_query->have_posts() ) : $movie_query->the_post(); 
    // Do stuff
   endwhile; ?>

 <div class="navigation">
<div class="previous panel"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; newer') ?></div>
<div class="next panel"><?php next_posts_link('older &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, however, I can't rely on `WP_Query` class as I need to construct my own custom SQL. I got there at the end, see my reply if interested :)

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

global $wpdb, $paged;
query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=9');
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$author = isset($_GET['author_name']) ? get_userdatabylogin($author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=9');

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'meta_query' => array(
        'meta_key' => 'autor',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_value' => $author->id,
            ),
'paged' => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => 9,
'order'    => 'DESC'
);

$postsQuery = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

Template:

```
<h1>Články od <?php echo $author->display_name; ?></h1>
        <ul class="thumbnails">

            <?php while ( $postsQuery->have_posts() ) : $postsQuery->the_post();  ?>
                <li class="span3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(260, 259)); ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    $class = '';
                    if (in_category('fashion')) {
                    $class = "link-fashion";
                    } else if (in_category('beauty')) {
                    $class = "link-beauty";
                    } else if (in_category('gourmet')) {
                    $class = "link-gourmet";
                    } else if (in_category('lifestyle')) {
                    $class = "link-lifestyle";
                    } else if (in_category('about-us')) {
                    $class = "link-about";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h2 class="<?=  $class ?>">
                        <span></span>
                        <?php
                        // short_title('...', 25); 
                        echo get_the_title();
                        ?>
                    </h2>
                    </a>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>
        <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code, also, why are you running two queries, one with `query_posts` and one with `WP_Query`